# openNI interferes with cvCreateCameraCapture()

Tags: exception, opencv, openni

I am using opencv 2.3 on ubuntu 11.04. while compiling, for completeness, I'd set WITH_OPENNI=ON. (regret it now, because I dont plan to use a kinect soon, and openni is giving me headaches with normal opencv programs)

anyway, to test the opencv installation i compiled following code that shows me video from my laptop webcam:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "highgui.h"
#include "cv.h"

int main()
{
cvNamedWindow("Webcam",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
CvCapture* capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
IplImage* frame;

while(1)
{
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frame) break;
    cvShowImage("Webcam",frame);
    char c=cvWaitKey(33);
    if(c==27) break;
}

cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
cvDestroyWindow("Webcam");
}
```

the code complies correctly but gives the following error on execution:

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Failed to enumerate production trees: Can't create any node of the requested type!) in CvCapture_OpenNI, file /home/samarth/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_openni.cpp, line 188
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /home/samarth/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_openni.cpp:188: error: (-2) Failed to enumerate production trees: Can't create any node of the requested type! in function CvCapture_OpenNI

Aborted

has anybody faced the same problem? any idea to cure this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed in OpenCV 2.3.1 release.

See following link for the details:
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1237